# How to populate pandas series w/ values from another df?

Tags: pandas

I need help figuring out how to populate a series of one dataframe w/ specific values from another dataframe.

Here's a sample of what I'm working with:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Year':[1910, 1911, 1912], 
                    'CA':[2.406, 2.534, 2.668], 
                    'HI':[0.804, 0.821, 0.832]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'State':['CA', 'CA', 'CA', 'HI', 'HI'], 
                    'Year':[1910, 1910, 1911, 1911, 1911]})

df2['Population'] = pd.Series()
```

*I'm trying to populate df2['Population'] w/ the corresponding populations from df1 (i.e. the population of a specific state from a specific year)

How can I do this?

Comment: Search for pd.query and then when combined with iloc webcam achieve what you desire...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be moved to the general SE site, this is a question about coding

Comment: That's fine with me, user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a one solution:

```
df2['Population'] = df2.apply(lambda x: df1.loc[x['Year'] == df1['Year'], x['State']].reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
```

The idea is for each row of `df2` we use the `Year` column to tell us which row of `df1` to access, and then `State` to select the column.  Afterwards we reset the index of the result to prevent pandas from keeping the columns separate.

Comment: Thanks dsaxton for your response. This is an elegant solution :)  For some reason I can't adapt it to my actual problem but it certainly works beautifully for this example. I'll keep trying.